# Sending values from multiple clicked checkboxes with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have created multiple checkboxes in table dynamically. Each checkbox has a hidden field with the column id which is to be send to the server but it only sends the value of the first checkbox if its clicked and does not iterate over the whole table. I have tried to look for a solution but its still producing the same result. Here is the code snippet:

```js
var tdCheck = $('<td>').html('').attr({
  'id': 'check'
}).appendTo(trbody);
var checkfield = $('<input>').html('').attr({
  'type': 'checkbox',
  'id': 'select',
  'value': entered[i].id
}).addClass('form-control').appendTo(tdCheck);
var br = $('<br>').html('').appendTo(tdCheck);
var hiddenfield = $('<input>').html('').attr({
  'id': 'columnid',
  'type': 'hidden',
  'value': entered[i].id
}).appendTo(tdCheck);
```

Code for ajax call

```
 $('#accept').click(function() {
   $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
     var columnId = [];
     columnId[i] = $('#columnid').val();
     JSON.stringify(columnId[i]);
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/ProductApproval/handlers/ProductApproval.ashx',
       data: {
         Action: "ApprovalStatus",
         ColumnId: columnId[i],
         flag: 1 //status for accept
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: you are repeating the id for the check boxes. But there should be unique id. Instead of id use class. this is repeating id `'id': 'columnid',` over here again `'id': 'select',`. Hence Js is taking the 1st one by default.

Comment: If you are appending the checkboxes at run time, better to use `.on('click')` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: Or you can use dynamic ID like columnid_1,columnid_1...etc.

Comment: @Samir i have tried to use class but its still not iterating and yes its appending at runtime but the effect of using `.on('click') and `.click()` is the seems to be the same